# Is there a way to get the Applications Submitted metric using the Insights edge of the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I am trying get the metric **Applications Submitted** seen in the image.  I am using v18 of the Graph API directly with HTTP.  I am using the Ad Account node with the Insights edge, but no matter what combination of parameters I use, it never returns the Applications Submitted (submit_application_total) metric.  I created a report (see image) and that works correctly.  I've been trying for over a week to get the same values with the Graph API with no breakthrough in sight (no pun intended).

[Sample Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVlYI.png)

These are examples of that I've used so far:

*Simple*

```
act_[acct_id]/insights?level=ad&fields=action_values&time_range={"since":"2023-10-01","until":"2023-10-31"}&limit=100&access_token=[token]
```

*Complex*

```
act_[acct_id]/insights?level=ad&fields=spend,reach,frequency,cost_per_unique_click,cpp,cpc,impressions,actions,action_values{"submit_application_total"}&action_breakdowns=action_type&action_report_time=impression&action_attribution_window=['1d_click','1d_view']&time_range={"since":"2023-10-01","until":"2023-10-01"}&limit=100&access_token=[token]
```

Each one works, but the result never contains the Total Applications Submitted or even a matching action_type.

The payload I'm getting looks like this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "spend": "21.28",
      "reach": "316",
      "frequency": "1.120253",
      "cost_per_unique_click": "2.128",
      "cpp": "67.341772",
      "cpc": "1.52",
      "impressions": "354",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "6"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "6"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": "5"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2023-10-01",
      "date_stop": "2023-10-01"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "NQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  If this is not possible, please let me know if there is a workaround.